# Probability of a random vector

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

I've got the random vector (X,Y), which is defined by the following density function:
$$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
6x&~\text{ if}~ (x,y)\in T \\
0&~\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

$T$ : a triangle with formed by the vertex on $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$.
We also have a new random variable called $Z$, where $Z=X+Y$ and $z$ is a real number between $(0,1)$.

---

My question is: how can I write $P(Z\le z)$ in function of $z$?

---

I've written $P(Z\le z)=(X+Y\le z)=P((X,Y)\in B)$, where $B={(X,Y) | y\le z-x}$
But know how can I calculate $P((X,Y) \in B)$ ?

Is it ok if I do the double integral (where $x$ goes from zero to $1$ and $y$ goes from zero to $z-x$), of $6x dy dx$ ? From where I reach this solution: $3z-(1/3)$.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct with one minor error. Obviously $x$ cannot be larger than $z$. Therefore the integral you need is:
$$
\int_0^z 6x\,dx\int_0^{z-x}dy=z^3.
$$